# Equidimensional Morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, schemes, dimension-theory

I am reading the paper "Relative Cycles and Chow Sheaves" due to Suslin and Voevodsky. Here we have the following definition:

Definition 2.1.2.

A morphism of schemes $p:X\rightarrow S$ is called an equidimensional morphism of dimension $r$  if the following conditions hold:

1.$p$ is a morphism of finite type.

2.The function $\dim(X/S)$ is constant and equals $r$.

3.Any irreducible component of $X$ dominates an irreducible component of $S$.

I would like to understand what the condition 3. means ... Thank you  a lot!!!

Comment: It means that given any irreducible component $X_i$ of $X$, there is an irreducible component $S_j$ of $S$ such that $p(X_i)$ contains an open subset of $S_j$. Please use [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) for this type of questions.

Comment: Thank you abx!!... Why should I use MSE?

Comment: The question is fine, and indicates a participation in mathematics at a professional level.